# Transforming SHA-512 into SHA-512/256?

Tags: hash, sha-2, sha-512

Based on my skimming over [FIPS 180-4](http://dx.doi.org/10.6028/NIST.FIPS.180-4) it looks like the only difference between SHA-512 and SHA-512/256 is the initial hash value and the fact that the final output is truncated to 256 bits.

My question is:  if you have a library that does SHA-512 can you transform that to SHA-512/256?

Like maybe there could be some sort of magic string that, when prepended to the original message, makes the first 256 bytes of the SHA-512 hash of the original message the same as SHA-512/256? Or maybe you could xor the first x bytes of the original message with some magic string?

I'm guessing that there isn't such a way but I thought I'd ask all the same.

Comment: because of the length built into the padding, there is not some prefix that will do what you want, or some way of modifying the message to do what you want.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like Richie Frame commented, as SHA-2 padding uses the length of the message that is not possible. Specifically, even if you had some string of input that took you from the SHA-512 IV to the SHA-512/256 IV, any message you hashed with it prepended would have a different length and thus a different hash value.

Additionally, even ignoring the padding it would be infeasible to find such a string. The IV constants for SHA-512/n have been chosen [using an algorithm](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/35026/13625) that does not start with the normal SHA-512 IV, so it would require a preimage attack on the compression function to find one.

However, unless you need compatibility or conformance with SHA-512/256, you could just use SHA-512 and truncate. See page 27 of the FIPS document you linked.